# Dynamically Populated Table view Reload Data IOS

Tags: ios, json, refresh

I m trying to implement a "refresh" button for my app. The app parses a Json file and puts the data in a table view. I want to make a button that when pressed it tries to connect to the server and fetch the updated data.
What I have done till now:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

and I have a method called refresh:

```
-(void) refresh{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work at all.

The way I get the Json data is this:

```
    #import "JSONLoader.h"
#import "Location.h"
#import "Reachability.h"

@implementation JSONLoader


- (NSArray *)locationsFromJSONFile:(NSURL *)url {


    // Create a NSURLRequest with the given URL
    NSError *requestError = nil;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                         timeoutInterval:30.0];

    // Get the data
    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];


    // Now create a NSDictionary from the JSON data
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    // Create a new array to hold the locations
    NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Get an array of dictionaries with the key "locations"
    NSArray *array = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"locations"];
    // Iterate through the array of dictionaries
    for(NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        // Create a new Location object for each one and initialise it with information in the dictionary
        Location *location = [[Location alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:dict];
        // Add the Location object to the array
        [locations addObject:location];
    }

    // Return the array of Location objects
    return locations;
    }



@end
```

How Can I make the refresh button work?

Comment: where you calling your refresh function?

Comment: is your data contains data??

Comment: Yes it contains data and it works as intended.the problem is that when a user opens the app with no internet connection the data is not fetched. When internet is active it works ok. What i m trying to do is make the refresh button reconnect and fetch the data when the user has internet again.

Comment: you wanna check automatically update your tableview when internet on or when you tap a button want to reload?

Answer (score 0):

k then you have to study or know to use about [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) concept its useful for chackin if network connection is there are not using that you can check network connection based on that you can check and refresh table.

First create BOOL function to check internet

```
+(BOOL)networkStatusAvailable{

    Reachability *internetReach =  [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [internetReach startNotifier];

    Reachability *wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] ;
    [wifiReach startNotifier];

    NetworkStatus netStatusInternetConnection = [internetReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    NetworkStatus netStatusLocalWiFi = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(netStatusInternetConnection == NotReachable && netStatusLocalWiFi == NotReachable)
    {
        return netStatusInternetConnection;
    }
    else
    {
        return netStatusInternetConnection;
    }

}
```

Hope you stored your json data properly how you can refresh means you can do two things one is directly reloading in button press or you can call the function

Then check the bool and refresh table

```
    - (IBAction)refreshTable:(id)sender
    {

       if(networkStatusAvailable)
        {
       [self.tableView reloadData];
       }
       else
        {
          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                message:@"No network Connection" 
                                                delegate:self 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
           [alert show];
        }

    }
```

or otherWise

```
- (void)refreshTable
{
   if(networkStatusAvailable)
        {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
       }
       else
        {
          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                message:@"No network Connection" 
                                                delegate:self 
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
           [alert show];
        }
}


- (IBAction)refreshTable:(id)sender
{

   [self refreshTable];

}
```

you can try like this and make sure your Delegate and datasource has been connected and if i did any wrong pls let me no it

Comment: I check for reachability and I display an alert when no internet.I tried - (IBAction)refreshTable:(id)sender{
       [tableView reloadData];} but I get an error No known class method for selector 'reloadData'

Comment: k then instead of NSLog you show using UIAlertView i ve updated my answer check that

Comment: ve you connected tableView with delegate and datasource ?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the

```
-(void) refresh{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

method it refreshes the table view only but the table view loads the data that has been previously fetched from server. You need to call the method where you fetch the data from server again.

Your refresh method should look something like that:

```
-(void) refresh
{
JSONLoader *aLoader = [JSONLoader alloc] init]; //init loader object
NSArray *newLocations = [aLoader locationsFromJSONFile:yourUrl]; //get the updated locations from server
self.oldLocations = newLocations; // assigning old array you used in table view datasource to the new data
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

You should note that loading data from server takes more time than reloading table view. I usually use the completion block to update the table when the data fetched completely or you can use a delegate method.

Comment: Sadly I cant do that because the prossess of generating a dictionary and putting the data in the table view are in different files. And self.oldlocations = newLocations isnt recognized as a JSONLoader object. What i m trying to do is make this "refresh" button reload the whole app from the start. Is possible somehow? I tryed abort() but the app crashes and i dont think its the right way.

Comment: NO-no you do not need to restart the app. You need to refresh the "oldlocations" array with new locations before calling the reloadData method from table view. You need to #import "JSONLoader.h" to the table view controller and use the locationsFromJSONFile method to refresh the "oldlocations" array. I beleive you did that. You call this method once at some place when your app starts, aren't you? Then you assign the method return to your "oldlocations" array in the table view controller.  So you should to that again at the "refresh" button tap.